# ListView item with checkbox - how to remove checkbox ripple effect?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, material-design, android-checkbox

I have a ListView with item contains a checkbox and some other elements. The problem is when I click on the list item on Android 5+ device I have it looks like this:

[image]

I don't want to have ripple effect around the checkbox.
How can I acheive that?

Item XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_check"
        android:checked="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:clickable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:lines="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set checkbox background :                    android:background="@null"

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try setting Background as Transparent to Checkbox

> android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Hope it helps.Thanks

Comment: Thanks! It really helped.

Comment: thank you this really bugged me i tried setting clickable to false focusable, focusable in touch mode, parent using block descendants 

Comment: I would use - android:background="@null"